# FileCatalyst android file send pause and resume: File is being written in another session

Tags: java, android, file-transfer

We are making Android application that have capability to send files to server. We used third party tool called FileCatalyst. FileCatalyst server configured in Linux machine. For the Android part a problem arises when resume the transfer after reconnecting. It says :

```
File is being written in another session
```